# OpenCPU docker image fails with libssl.so.1.0.0 invalid ELF header

Tags: r, docker, opencpu

I have run into a problem with the latest [opencpu/base](https://hub.docker.com/r/opencpu/base/) and [opencpu/rstudio](https://hub.docker.com/r/opencpu/rstudio/) docker images. They are failing right from the start:

```
> docker run --name ocpu -t -p 80:80 opencpu/rstudio
/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: invalid ELF header
```

As I understand right, This is because of `rstudio-server` was being compiled on a different OS. What is the better solution to fix this issue? Build sources within the clean Linux image?

UPDATE:
I have tried [opencpu/ubuntu-16.04](https://hub.docker.com/r/opencpu/ubuntu-16.04/) image and it works fine. The problem only exists for `base` and `rstudio` images.